# Div with multiple classes is being misread by browser

Tags: html, css

I have an html code

`<div class="required-fields group-summary field-group-html-element">testing</div>`

I include also a css

`div.group-summary { float:right;}`

but it doesn't work.

If however I try:

`div.required-fields.group-summary.field-group-html-element { float:right;}`

then it works just fine. Is there something that I am missing. It seems so simple that I can't believe where the problem may be.

Comment: Works with both versions (Firefox 20), see http://jsfiddle.net/m3gV6/

Comment: This would happen if you had other css rules that affect the div, you need to use your browsers developer tools to inspect what else is targeting the `div`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second rule `div.required-fields.group-summary.field-group-html-element` is more specific than the first one and might override a third contrary rule, which is more specific than the first but less specific than the second rule, e.g.

```
div.group-summary {
    float:right;
}

div.required-fields.group-summary {
    float: left;
}
```

will `float: left`, whereas

```
div.required-fields.group-summary {
    float: left;
}

div.required-fields.group-summary.field-group-html-element {
    float:right;
}
```

will `float: right`.

Comment: I see, thank you! There are many rules doing various things to divs so I'll have to review this first.